# if ka + lb = 1, then a and b are relatively prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Me and a friend are having a small arguement. My friend says the statement is false but I'm saying its true.

My friend thinks its false because ka + lb does not necessarily equal 1. Rather, it can equal anything as long as k and l holds.

I say its true because the gcd(a,b) = d = ka + lb, a theorem we used earlier.

We understand this is supposed to be easy, but we can't agree on this.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ have a common factor, then would that common factor divide $ka+lb$?

Comment: Perhaps it's a confusion of "quantifiers".  If there exist integers $k,\ell$ such that $ka+\ell b = 1$, then integers $a,b$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 1):

One can show the ideal $I=\{ka+lb\mid k,l\in\mathbf Z\}$ is equal to the ideal generated by $\gcd(a,b)$. Hence if $ka+lb=1$ for some $k,l\in \mathbf Z$, $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Indeed, if $d=k_0 a+l_0 b$ is the smallest positive element of $I$, you can perform a Euclidean division of $a$ by $d$: $a=qd+r\enspace(0\le r<d)$. Then
$$0\le r=a-qd=(1-qk_0)a -ql_0b$$
is a non-negative element of $I$ which is smaller than $d$. By the minimality of $d$, we have $r$, i. e. $d$ divides $a$. For similar reasons, $d$ divides $b$.